# Show() when class "tip" is found not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying find a "tip" class in every "animate" class and then display their "animate" class with `show()` if there is a tip class found in it.

There seems to be something wrong with my code because it's not working at all.

**My attempt:**

```
if($('.animate').find('.tip').length === 1) {
    $(this).show();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="foobar">
    <div class="animate">
        <div class="tip">- This is a tip.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="animate">
        <div>- This is not a tip.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="animate">
        <div class="tip">- This is a tip.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to consider each `$('.animate')` in turn;

```
$('.animate').each(function () {
    if ($(this).find('.tip').length) {
        $(this).show();
    }
});
```

... although you could also use the [`has()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) to do this in one line;

```
$('.animate:has(.tip)').show();
```

However, I guess you'll also want to *hide* the elements which don't match the selector, so you can do that via ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/322Cq/));

```
$('.animate').each(function () {
    $(this).toggle(!!$(this).find('.tip').length);
});
```

... or ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/322Cq/1/)):

```
$('.animate').hide().filter(':has(.tip)').show();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That one-liner so handy!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are not getting the `this` issue right

```
$(".animate").each(function(){
    if($(this).find(".tip").length===1){
        $(this).show();
    });
});
```